# Insert list into MySQL database using Python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am doing a classification using k-nearest neighbor with python. The data I am using is float type, `latitude` and `longitude` and get the output from it like this:

prediction

```
preds2 = model.predict(new_list)
print(type(preds2))
print(preds2)
print("-----------")
print(new_list)
print(type(new_list))
print("-----------")
```

Output prediction not merged

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
['Taman Suaka Margasatwa Angke' 'Taman Suaka Margasatwa Angke']
-----------
[[-6.1676580997222, 106.9042428], [-6.1676580997222, 106.9042428]]
<class 'list'>
```

Merge them together

```
mergedata = [[*new_list, preds2] for new_list, preds2 in zip(new_list, preds2)]
print(mergedata)
```

output from `mergedata`

```
[[-6.1676580997222, 106.9042428, 'Taman Suaka Margasatwa Angke'], [-6.1676580997222, 106.9042428, 'Taman Suaka Margasatwa Angke']]
```

I want to store the output from `mergedata` to database mysql so this is the code that I've tried

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='destinasi',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='')

mycursor = connection.cursor()
myArray = mergedata
arraySize = len(myArray)
for r in range(0,arraySize):
    try:
        mycursor.execute(
       """INSERT INTO hasilclass (Latitude,Longitude,Class) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",
            (",".myArray[r], )
        )
        connection.commit()
    except:
        print("Error")
        connection.rollback()
```

The output is:

```
Error
Error
```

This is the display of database in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `hasilclass` (
  `Latitude` float(15,11) NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` float(15,11) NOT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(55) NOT NULL
)
```

It seems that `mycursor.execute` is not executing the mysql statement, i don't know the correct way to do it. Any Suggestions how to correct it? is the statement is false? all the data is from mysql as well but im using pymysql to call all the data and do all the work untill i need to store them to database.

The reference in the internet i found is using mysql.connector to store 2 dimensional list in python so i follow it and it goes error like this.

Comment: You are specifying 3 bound params but only supplying a tuple with one element. Your tuple should have the same number of elements as bound params.

Comment: @jordanm Thankyou for replying this.. do you mean this one? (",".myArray[r], )

Comment: What are you trying to do with `(",".myArray[r], )`? Do you mean to `join()` here? If so, don't do that. Instead, pass `myArray[r]` as a parameter directly to `execute()` so it can safely replace the values in the query. For more information, you should read about SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to build a tuple with a single element. However, it doesn't work the way you want because `",".myArray` tries to get a property named `myArray` from the string `","`, but this doesn't exist. Instead, `myArray` is a global variable that you want to access.

To do this, change

```
            (",".myArray[r], )
```

to

```
            myArray[r]
```

Also, in Python, we prefer to iterate over the elements of an array directly rather than counting the indexes. This means you can change

```
arraySize = len(myArray)
for r in range(0,arraySize):
```

to

```
for row in myArray:
```

And now you can simplify your SQL command further:

```
        mycursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO hasilclass (Latitude,Longitude,Class) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
            row
        )
```

Finally, a warning that assigning

```
myArray = mergedata
```

does not make a copy. This doesn't look like it does much of anything for you so I suggest removing it. Instead, just use `mergedata` directly:

```
for row in mergedata:
```

Comment: Thankyou very much sir... it works!!. im so gratefull to you, i really appreciate it.